# Is it reasonable to assume modern computers can do hardware math with integers up to 2^64?

Tags: computer-architecture, space-complexity, computation-models, memory-hardware, bit-manipulation

I was writing up an algorithm that involved knowing the size of integers my hardware can manage without having to resort to software implementations of math operations and the additional computational load that comes with them, and I realized that I've never given this much thought.

In theory, a 64-bit computer has 64 lines on the address/data bus, and thus can't send an integer to the CPU's ALU any higher than 2^64-1, making that the starting point. But I also know that some modern hardware has support for SIMD operations with 256-bit data, or even higher, and how that's possible I don't know (multiple operations to load in the data, 64 bits at a time, I assume?).

Without limiting this question to specific hardware, which would greatly diminish its usefulness, is there a reasonable rule of thumb for how large of an integer a typical modern computer (2015-2020 era) can handle in a single go?

Comment: A 64 bit computer most definitely doesn't have anywhere near 64 lines on the address bus, and most will have a lot more than 64 lines on the data bus. Your mental model is very, very wrong here - probably because you are ignoring cache memory.

Comment: The ALU is part of the CPU. Data doesn't get sent there on any external bus.

Comment: Just saying: "Modern" is not necessarily powerful. There are many tiny, tiny CPUs around that have very little power and are dirt cheap. But for the "computer" in a cheap modern smartphone assuming 64 bit capabilities is not unreasonable. I might be able to find an iPhone 4 somewhere at the bottom of a drawer that is 32 bit only, but nobody will install any software on it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can look at the instruction set for that CPU architecture. If it has (for example) an "add 64 bits to 64 bits" instruction then you know it can do that.

Current 64-bit CPUs do support the full set of ALU operations on 64-bit numbers. Add, subtract, multiply, divide, bitshift, bitwise operations, modulo, maybe some that I forgot. *All* of the usual instructions work on 64-bit numbers in one go. That's why we call them 64-bit CPUs.

The address and data bus paradigm is quite outdated. Nowadays CPUs transfer data in big chunks, up to the size of a cache line (usually 64 bytes). Actually, if you read just 1 byte, the CPU will read 512 bits from main memory into the cache, read 512 bits from the cache, and discard 504 of them. (or maybe 256 and discard 248) The data bus is *very* wide, and SIMD operations let you use its full potential.

If there's no "add 256 bits to 256 bits" instruction then you still can't do that in one go. SIMD operations will surely help you add lots of big numbers quickly, but if the instruction you want doesn't exist then you'll still need to write an addition algorithm yourself (using SIMD if you want)

Comment: M1 reads/writes up to 1024 bytes at a time. Enough so that 20 CPU cores can’t saturate the memory bus.